# Why is one project in my solution bold

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution

In my solution, I have one project whose name is bold.

[image]

Why is `ErrorHandlerLibrary` bold?

Comment: It's your [startup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx).

Comment: +1 I don't think this question deserves a down vote.

Comment: [MSDN also states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26k97dbc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) By default, the first project created in the solution is designated as the startup project, but you can change which projects run first when you build or run your solution For more information, see How to: Set Startup Projects.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because for whatever reasons, for debugging or release purposes, Visual Studio has chosen that project as your `Startup Project`.  These projects run automatically when starting the Visual Studio debugger.  This also means that you have the option to run multiple projects when the debugger starts.  To read more, [check Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26k97dbc(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The project that is started when starting the debugger is emboldened. If you want to change it, you can right click and set a different as the start-up project

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is set as your "startup" project. You can right click the others and change the startup project that way.